# creating a class within a class and returning data from database

Tags: c#

I created a class within a class so it could be an alternative to writing 3 different methods calling
          to the database- so i created a class with related items and now when i try to build i get the error
          `Cannot implicity convert type System.collections.generic.list<anonymousType#1> to class that i created StudentDocuments`
          and when i click on the error it directs me to the `return subs` statement.

```
public class  StudentDocuments
    {
        public Guid DocID {get; set;}
        public string Assignment {get; set;}
        public DateTime Submitted {get; set;}
        public string Student {get;set;}
    }




public StudentDocuments GetStudentSubmissionGrid(Guid usr, Guid lib)
    {
        using (var dc = new DocMgmtDataContext())
        {
            var subs = (from doc in dc.Documents
                        join u in dc.Users on doc.OwnedByUserID equals u.ID
                        where doc.OwnedByUserID == usr && doc.LibraryID == lib
                        select new { 
                            DocID = doc.ID, 
                            Assignment = doc.Library.Name, 
                            Submitted = doc.UploadDT,
                            Student = u.FullName
                        })
                .OrderByDescending(c => c.Submitted).ToList();
            return subs;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You create anonymous type your LINQ. Instead you must create the specific type object list according your return type.

Use this:

```
select new StudentDocuments{ 
                               DocID = doc.ID, 
                               Assignment = doc.Library.Name, 
                               Submitted = doc.UploadDT,
                               Student = u.FullName
                           }
```

and declare your method as:

```
public List<StudentDocuments> GetStudentSubmissionGrid(Guid usr, Guid lib)
```

You can also return `IEnumerable<StudentDocuments>` instead of list.

**UPDATE**

```
var subs = (from doc in dc.Documents
                    join u in dc.Users on doc.OwnedByUserID equals u.ID
                    where doc.OwnedByUserID == usr && doc.LibraryID == lib
                    orderby doc.UploadDT descending
                    select new StudentDocuments
                     { 
                        DocID = doc.ID, 
                        Assignment = doc.Library.Name, 
                        Submitted = doc.UploadDT,
                        Student = u.FullName
                     }).AsEnumerable().ToList();
```

Comment: Thanks i think this will work but now it is telling me that i cannot implicity convert type iqueryable  studentDocument to a list and that i might be missing a cast.

Comment: As an aside, you might want to think about having the `GetStudentSubmissionGrid` function return an `IEnumerable`, rather than returning a `List`. The benefit of this is that if you use LINQ further up to select a smaller list, it'll save some database work. (totally unrelated to answering the question, though).

Comment: @ColinDeClue advise considered and changed from `List` to `IEnumerable` thanks for explanation.